# Docker - Running nginx as a proxy for Redmine

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, redmine, docker-compose

I'd like to Dockerize the setup for an nginx to redmine (and other services) reverse proxy, but when forwarding requests from nginx to redmine, I'm seeing a 501 bad gateway request on browsers and a `"failed (111 Connection refused)"` on the nginx output.

The nginx configuration works with regular nginx server (non-dockerized) forwarding requests to a dockerized redmine server, which leads me to believe I've done something screwy with the network. I can also access the the redmine server directly via port 3000.

Here's a snippet of my setup:

nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        # Seeing a 501 Bad Gateway on the browser
        location /redmine {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        networks:
            - shared_internal
    redmine:
        image: redmine
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            - shared_internal
networks:
    shared_internal:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I haven't looked at [Bukharov Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357128/865883) yet, so that may be more elegant.

---

Here's what I've come up with. I've found 2 methods for achieving the network sharing capability and 1 hack for a Redmine issue that appears when using said methods.

**Method 1 (Preferred because it's shorter, but maybe not because it's deprecated?): [Container Linking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)**

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        # Method 1: Linking
        links:
            - redmine
    redmine:
        image: redmine
        # Method 1: Exposing port to linked containers
        expose:
            - "3000"
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

# Method 1: Access via alias from link
        location /redmine/ {
            proxy_pass http://redmine:3000/;
        }
}
```

**Method 2: [Defining a Network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-in-user-defined-networks)**

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        # Method 2
        networks:
            shared_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.22.0.4
    redmine:
        image: redmine
        # Method 2
        networks:
            shared_net:
                ipv4_address: 172.22.0.5
# Method number 2: Via networks
networks:
    shared_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
                  gateway: 172.22.0.1
```

nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

# Method 2: Access via ip address in shared network
        location /redmine_networked/ {
            proxy_pass http://172.22.0.5:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Redmine Hack: [Accessing redmine via a suburl](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI)

The above solutions allow for access to Redmine's home page. All the Redmine URLs, though, will point to root (e.g. '/' for home, instead of '/redmine' or '/redmine_networked'). So none of those links will work. If nginx was setup to redirect all '/' urls to Redmine, this would be a non-issue. The following hack assumes that is not the case.

To get Redmine to point to the URLs configured, one will need to edit the config/environment.rb file.

Here's the hack:

```
 > docker exec -it <redmine_container> bash
 redmine> cd config
# We're going to install vim (this is a hack)
 redmine> apt-get update 
 redmine> apt-get install vim
 redmine> vim environment.rb
```

> Change the following lines at the bottom of your config/environment.rb
>
> ```
> Initialize the Rails application Rails.application.initialize!
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> RedmineApp::Application.routes.default_scope = "/redmine" 
> Initialize the Rails application Rails.application.initialize!
> ```

```
redmine> exit
> docker restart <redmine> (or just kill other docker process and run docker up again)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nginx proxy container](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/)
nginx-proxy sets up a container running nginx and docker-gen. docker-gen generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx when containers are started and stopped.

it is more convenient then manual configuration nginx